# LibGDX - pass a class to a function as parameter

Tags: function, class, libgdx

```
Game game;
Skin skin;
...
Button btn = new Button(skin);
btn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        changeScreenTo( *some class* );
    }
});

void changeScreenTo( * ) {
    // do stuff
    ...
    game.setScreen( * )
}
```

I am making a game using LibGDX.

I wanted to pass some class as a parameter to the function, then I would use that class to set the screen. I couldn't find any way to do that. What should I do?

**EDIT :** I want to do this because I want to call the constructor of the screen that is about to be set after I do the stuff in the function. This is where I am struggling.

Comment: Well the `setScreen` method takes a `Screen` class type parameter. So are you asking how to pass instances of classes that inherited from `Screen` to `setScreen`?

Comment: I mean I don't want to do `changeScreenTo(new MyScreen());`. I want to do like `changeScreenTo(MyScreen.class)` or something. Because I don't want to call the constructor of `MyScreen` before this line; `// do stuff`.

Comment: If the function takes an object of type Screen then you're gonna have to run the constructor.

Comment: I want to call the constructor when I set the screen.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do in `// do stuff` part. Cos if it's some unrelated to the screen stuff, you just could create separate method for stuff and then call `changeScreenTo` method.

Comment: Yes they are sort of unrelated. I can do that. I did not think of that, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome) should I post something as an answer?

Comment: You don't need to. Thanks again